# Open source engine that doesn't lose on time

Tags: engines

I'm looking for an open source engine (doesn't have to be very strong) that can be loaded with python chess uci module and can play at very fast time controls (few seconds plus tens of milliseconds of increment)

Thanks for your recommendations

Comment: I dont see any of the big engines losing on time in any time control. Which ones have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Stockfish is strong and able to handle your time control increments. Have you tried Stockfish?